# Is there shortcut to VCS commands in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, I have to click "VCS->git->pull" to update a project. How to configure the UI to make those operations executed by commands that are directly available to users?

Comment: You may also consider using [Quick Lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-quick-lists.html), these are extremely handy for the related actions and you don't have to remember multiple keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is assign a shortcut for specific command.

> Intellij -> Settings -> Keymap -> Version Control System -> Git ->
>   Repository

Then Right click on pull and

> add Keyboard shortcut

Or For Add Icon Pull to your Toolbar you can

> Right click on toolbar -> Customize Menus and Toolbars ->  open Main
>   Toolbar node -> click on position where you would like to put new
>   action -> Add After -> Select the action ( Main Menu - VCS
>   -  Git -  Repository - Pull -> OK )

If you want you can custom the icon also.

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot to show it? I want the icon for toolbar, but can't find where the toolbar is. I tried click but no effect.

Comment: Maybe the toolbar isn't display. You can show it with View -> Toolbar and then it will appear

Comment: "click on position where you would like to put new action"? where to click to add the git actions?

Comment: I got it. Thanks.